# Tumblr sharer URL override

Tags: tumblr

Tumblr has a sharer just like Facebook and Twitter, Tumblr's is: http://www.tumblr.com/share/.  I believe that Tumblr's works by looking at the referring URL and uses that.

I cannot seem to find any documentation to override that.  I want to pass in an additional key into the URL that is sent by default.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tumblr share URL as of Aug. 2014:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=[uri encoded URL]&amp;name=[title]&amp;description=[description]
```

Comment: This should still work as shown in their docs: https://www.tumblr.com/buttons  Under 'Share Buttons' go to Step 4 and click Javascript to see all the anchor link code.

Comment: My bad! Haven't encoded text before using. This works just fine.

Answer (score 16):

The URL format is as follows:

> http://tumblr.com/share?s=&v=3&t=[Title]&u=[uri
>   encoded URL]

This will pre-populate the share form with the chosen title and url. As noted the URL, or value of `u=` must be URI encoded to work properly.